# urlencode and GET request breaks at Ampersand

Tags: php, wordpress, get, urlencode

I am working on a wordpress website which has thousands of pages and the owner has entered an affiliate link for each page via a custom field named: afflink

The affiliate link is outputted on the page using:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'afflink', true) ?>
```

The user clicks the link which sends them to a page called go.php

The link looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/go/go.php?url=http://www.somesite.com/redirector.aspx?aid=334&cid=2502&tid=3
```

Within the go.php page is the following meta refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;<?php echo $_GET['url']?>
```

" />

However, when the page refreshes it sends us to just:

```
http://www.somesite.com/redirector.aspx?aid=334
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `urlencode` before printing link to the user, not after he clicks the link:

```
$link = "http://www.somesite.com/redirector.aspx?aid=334&cid=2502&tid=3";
echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/go/go.php?url='.urlencode($link).'">' . $link . '</a>';
```

[+]

I strongly recommend writing some script that will change existing entries with proper ones. If all of them starts with `www.mysite.com/go/go.php?url=` then you can replace it with nothing in database, add this part to your meta tag and echo urlencoded link from db.

Any other solution will be just a kludge. One of it is to recreate original url from the rest of GET parameters in go.php:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
unset($_GET['url']);
if ($_GET) {
    $url .= '&' . http_build_query($_GET);
}
```

Comment: Yes that would work fine if I was inputting the original link directly in to $link but because we are retrieving from the url parameter it is breaking at ampersand

Comment: @AlanCarr So you don't have any control over how this link is generated for user to click?

Comment: The link is added in Wordpress via a custom field. To echo the link on the page where the user would click it we use:                             <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'afflink', true) ?>

Comment: Please update your question with this and add some more code - does this function return only link (`http://www.somesite...`) or entire html?

Comment: Update, please check the revised question, that should be a lot clearer

Comment: If it returns the whole link to your site withe other link as parameter, then it was incorrectly provided in custom wordpress field. URL parameter in this link should be urlencoded before storing it.

Comment: Hi yes, I'm aware of that, but there are thousands of links already added by the client, that's why I'm trying to figure out if there is a work around otherwise each one will need to be changed one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing URLs.

Your URL is parsed like this:

- Path: `go/go.php`
- `?`
- First query string argument: `url=http://www.somesite.com/redirector.aspx?aid=334`
- `&`
- Second querystring argument: `cid=2502`
- `&`
- Third querystring argument: `tid=3`

Instead, you need to URL-parameter-encode the inner URL.

Answer (score 0):

No need to urldecode a GET or REQUEST variable, they are automatically decoded:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php