# problems with sending value with $_get

Tags: php, html, get, anchor

Have a ***list of links*** on the side which when ***clicked*** will ***generate relevant content*** using $_GET.

Issue:

- The full value if not received by $_GET. For example
  Trainers & Sportswear

  **The value I GET is** 
      - $_GET['category'] = *trainers*

  **Instead of** 
      - $_GET['category'] = *trainers & sportswear*

Actually $_GET breaks after space in the text links. Like "Nike Trainers" will return only "Nike".

Note: Would using onClick () be a possible solution.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Happy Coding!

Comment: using `$_GET[]` means the vales are in the URL. Is your URL url-encoded?

Comment: No I am generating the list of categories from MySQL.

Comment: you can't put "&", it would have another meaning in a url

Comment: Okay. But there are other texts without '&' and as soon as a space comes the value of $_GET is set up to the space in text like "Nike Trainers" would be just 'Nike'

Comment: possible duplicate of [urlencode and GET request breaks at Ampersand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507909/urlencode-and-get-request-breaks-at-ampersand)

Comment: Okay, so basically the & needs to be **encoded**, or more generally, the URL should be. See; http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Ok I went through the php.net and used it & it worked. It was a simple error. Thanks Hamza and thanks every1 for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

first, replace spaces with `+` sign, next replace `&` with %26.

so `trainers & sportswear` would become `trainers+%26+sportswear`

that ought to work for you. `urlencode()` your string.

Answer (score 0):

See What Happens is that
$_GET has few restrictions
1. content is shown in the url.
2. the content can be posted to a limited size.

so here in ur case
the number of characters sent may be creating the problem.

Second thing is that
when we send a number of values in the url they are all separated by '&'
as like
a=4&b=6 and so on
so '&' is dividing the values.